# How to start rails server without database.yml and add DB later in initializers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, object-initializers

I need to do a HTTP call for getting the credentials of the actual DB to use. So I've added code to get the credentials and updating the active record connection in an initializer file but whenever I start rails server it is looking for development in database.yml. how to escape this?

Comment: add the value in database.yml as env value, `ENV["fetched value"]`

Comment: are you saying I update ENV value with the result of the external request and feed that ENV value to database.yml?

Comment: yes you are correct

Comment: Checkout https://mavens.github.io/2016/02/09/rails-multi-db to get some idea